# Simple way to an apparently hard combinatorial problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I would like to arrange $n$ different books in a shelf in such a way that three specific books can never be next to each other (no restrictions on the remaining $n-3$ books).

What is the number of different orders I can arrange the $n$ books?

The only way I can think of doing this is considering different cases:

One of the three books goes in the first of $n$ slots, the second goes in the third slot, etc. But this is too hard since there are too many possibilities.

I could also consider the cases where the three books are consecutive, then two of the books are consecutive but the third is not and subtract these counts to the overall count. However, I am not sure how to count the case when two of the three books are consecutive and the third is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Let $n$ be big enough, let say $n=7$. Let the other books be $B$.

arrange those books that are free from restriction first. There are $(n-3)!$ ways to arrange them.

$$*B*B*B*B*$$

The $*$ are the place holder of which the interesting $3$ books can be slot in.

There are $(n-3)+1$ such slots. We can pick $3$ of them to slot in our interesting book and we can rearrange them.  $\binom{n-2}{3} 3!$

Notice that when $n$ is small enough. We might not be able to separate the books.

Comment: When n=5, your formula doesnt seem to work. Also why the (n-3)+1 slots? Shouldnt it be n-3 slots?

Comment: what do you get when $n=5$?

Comment: I get $3!*2=12$. For $n=6$ I get $3! 3! 10$.

Comment: For $n=6$, my method should give $(3!)^2(4)$, is that the wrong answer?

Comment: For $n=5$, my formula and your answer agree.

Comment: Yes I agree, I was wrong on the $n=6$ case.